# Onclick listener throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've setup a button and I'm trying to display a toast when the user clicks on it. Here's my Java code -

```
file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.file);

file.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Display the file chooser dialog
                //showChooser();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Here's my XML code to setup the button -

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/file"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/plt"
            android:text="File" />
```

This throws a NullPointerException on the line `file.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Are you initializing the Button inside the onCreate() method of your Activity?

If so, please check if you are calling

```
setContentView(R.id.yourlayoutfile);
```

before initializing the Button with `findViewById(R.id.file);`

Your error occurs because your **Button "file" is `null`, which means that `findViewById(...)` didn't find any View with that id.** The reason therefore can either be that there is no such ID in the inflated layout, or that you didn't call `setContentView(...)`

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutfile);

        // initialize your button here  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to clean project

project-->clean-->choose your project-->ok,
then run again.

if you still facing the same problem you can use another way to set click action

in your XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/file"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/plt"

        <!--added line-->            
        android:onClick="anyName"

        android:text="File" />
```

and then in you activity remove the  initialization of the button and click listner too

and make the code looks like that

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.yourlayoutfile);
}

public void anyName(View v){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

Hope this help.

Comment: I'll add that the reason "clean project" is a potential fix is because sometimes (using Eclipse), `R.java` gets out of sync with the XML layouts you've written, and a clean build will regenerate `R.java` from scratch

Comment: Definitely, this is a very common problem when working with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Null pointer exception on this line:

```
file.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

then it mean your `file` object is null

Make sure you initialize your file object before adding a listener to it.